# matlab rgb values dilemma

Tags: matlab

When i wrote these commands

```
out = ones(size(ben))
imshow(out)
```

the output is a white picture but i expect almost dark picture because the rgb values are 1,1,1. when i give 255,255,255 it also gives a white picture. Isn't this a dilemma ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `out = ones(size(ben), 'uint8');`

`ones()` by default creates an array of doubles.  When `imshow()` gets an array of doubles it assumes that the pixel values range between 0 and 1, and assigns the white color to anything greater than 1.  However, if you pass an array of `uint8` to `imshow()` it will assume the range to be between 0 and 255.

You can also try using `imagesc();` instead of `imshow()`, but you may need to do `colormap gray` after wards to get a grayscale image.

Another alternative is to rescale the image before display:

```
imshow(out / max(out(:)));
```

Comment: Actually, in an 8-bit image, the values go from 0 to 255. Also, to show a scaled image, you can call `imshow(out,[])`

Comment: Good point!  I always try to remember that Matlab uses 1-based array indexing, and I guess I overdid it this time... :)